# How to handle converting dates to specific user timezone (Generic) MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've do a lot of researching about handling and converting dates in my application to work globally between timezones.

In my application user can choose from different UiCulture to display the web application and choose different timezone from the culture, like he/she can set the culture to en-US and set in his profile inside the database the timezone.
i have successfully achieved a generic way to convert the user input and store it in UTC format and restore it and formatting using the selected UiCulture.

I know i can use functions inside the controllers (or some other place), and btw i am using MVC, and i don't like doing copy-past code or repeating it.

Now, what i want is a generic way to handle the converting of time part of the date based on a user pre-defined timezone (dont want copy-past code in many places).

Converting the date to UTC has been done through model binder.

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        DateTime dateTime;
        string CleanedDate = Numbers.ArabicToEnglish(value.AttemptedValue);

        var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(CleanedDate, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);
        if (!isDate)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Invalid Nullable DateTime Value");
            return null;
        }
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

I don't know if i can achieve a timezone handling for inserting and restoring via using "**DefaultModelBinder**". using the methods

```
protected override void SetProperty
protected virtual object GetPropertyValue
```

I don't want client side solution.

Sorry for my bad english as it is not my first language, and i don't know if u get my issue because i don't really know how to describe it.

I did a lot of reading and searching and could not find similar behavior of what i want.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you are storing dates in UTC and you have the timezone of the user in db, then when the user logs into your application, you need to set the the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` and `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` in `Application_BeginRequest` to the timezone of the user. Not sure what is not working for you.

Comment: You are right i think, but culture can be different from timezone

Comment: yes they can be different. what is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: lets say the user set the website culture to ar-sy and want the time zone to be UK timezone, i dont think this will solve the problem